# Does Spotify Web API store user email and details of those who authorized?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I have created a Web application that makes use of the Spotify Web API. Through the spotify Web API, I get the user's email (which they used to register their spotify account) after they authorize my app on their end.  However, I don't store their emails in any database after they authorize. Is there a way I can retrieve the email list of all the users who authorized my app so far from my Spotify app interface?

Comment: I don't think there is, at least not in their public API. You would need to store that information in your database from now on.

Comment: Which OAuth flow did you use? Sounds like either Authorization Code or Implicit Grant.